# Does Adafruit's Wifi adapter work with Ubuntu on Raspberry PI 2?

Tags: wifi, ubuntu

Does Adafruit's Wifi adapter work with Ubuntu Trusty and Ubutu Snappy Core on Raspberry PI 2?

I've tried two other wifi adapter so far and both failed to work on Ubuntu. One also failed to work on Raspbian.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter works fine with Ubuntu for your desktop/laptop, however Snappy Core is a developer release and I dont believe that it has the drivers loaded to support the wifi adapter.  For a list of commands for Snappy type "snappy info" with your snappy micro sd installed in your RPi.  If you are just tinkering stick with Raspbian OS for the RPi.  Also I have had good luck with Realtek wifi dongles: rtl 8188CE, rtl8176 are chipsets that I know work (these are ones I use).  Be sure to check Amazon, Adafruit or Fry's Electronics if it is nearby  I hope this helps.

Comment: I am asking this before purchase of the Adafruit's Wifi dongle. I got myself Raspberry Pi 2 and now it doesn't work with any Wifi dongles. The dongle I get should work with this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi. It seems that Adafruit's dongle actually comes equiped with RTl8192/8188CUS Chipset (http://www.adafruit.com/products/814)

Comment: i purchased a usb wifi dongle from adafruit, with the chipset 8188CE, works fine.   both ubuntu and raspbian oses are derivates of debian linux.  i always check for compatibility with debian first then check the derivative os.  derivative oses rarely remove drivers from the parent os.  to be sure check (http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters#Working_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters).  hope this helps